# AWS Lambda, Terraform - Add Role to Lambda that References a Not-Yet-Created Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

**SOLUTION**: The trick was to create another role that isn't attached to the role of the lambda, but is assumed through STS.

TL;DR How do I create a role that a Lambda function can assume, that references the lambda, **before** the lambda has been created

Hello Folks,

I am using Terraform v1.0.5 along with AWS.  I have a lambda that has the following code in it:

```
assumed_role = sts_client.assume_role(
        ...
        RoleSessionName="tms_rules_settings_lambda",
        ...
    )
```

To do this, I have to give my lambda a policy that it can assume such a role.  Thus, I have the following Terraform.

```
locals {
  tms_rules_settings_lambda_role_name = "tms_rules_settings_lambda_role"
  tms_rules_settings_lambda_func_name = "tms_rules_settings_lambda"
}
...
** The Lambda Setup**
resource "aws_lambda_function" "tms_rules_settings_lambda" {
  ...
  function_name = local.tms_rules_settings_lambda_func_name
  role = aws_iam_role.tms_rules_settings_lambda_role.arn
  ...
}
...
** The Lambda Role Setup**
resource "aws_iam_role" "tms_rules_settings_lambda_role" {

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:assumed-role/${local.tms_rules_settings_lambda_role_name}/${local.tms_rules_settings_lambda_func_name}",
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF

}
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Error: Error creating IAM Role tms_rules_settings_lambda_role: 

MalformedPolicyDocument: Invalid principal in policy: 

"AWS":"arn:aws:sts::267601234567:assumed-role/tms_rules_settings_lambda_role/tms_rules_settings_lambda"
```

I believe this is being caused because the lambda and role reference one another, and when one doesn't exist it blows up.

How do I go about creating my role for the lambda when the principal (the lambda) doesn't exist.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Marcin I stopped trying to attach the role to the Lambda, and instead had a role attached to nothing.   The Lambda is given permission to assume this role.  So my code assumes that role and does what it needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you **can't do this**. A valid principle **must exist** before you can use it in any IAM policy or role. So you either have to use a wildcard in the principle arn, or first create the function, and then update its roles or permissions, once the lambda exists.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a role as a principal in a policy statement, you use the role ARN, not the assumed role principal that STS gives you.  You used the latter, and that's why you're getting the error.

However... it looks to me like you're trying to add a role to *it's own assumeRole policy*.  Why would you do that?  The role doesn't need to assume itself.

Comment: I'm doing it because I have to get a policy that is dynamic and restricted based on a TenantId (I'm also not too learned on the matter).  To do this I need to get credentials from STS which is where the role comes in.



    cognito_idp_client = session.client('cognito-idp', region_name=region_name,
                                        aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
                                        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                                        aws_session_token=credentials["SessionToken"], )

Comment: But `local.tms_rules_settings_lambda_role` is the same role as `aws_iam_role. tms_rules_settings_lambda_role`, right?  You are giving someone who has already assumed the role the ability to assume it, but they don't have to, because they already have it.  The lambda role will need to be different from the role with the tenantId if you want this to work.  You can check the session name (tennant ID) by writing a condition based on the sts:RoleSessionName condition key: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html#condition-keys-sts